# Does anyone know any service similar to Tropo?

Tags: voip, voice

I have used tropo and pretty happy with the service http://tropo.com/

Does anyone know of a reliable alternative?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/). I have used the API, it's very easy.

Answer (score 3):

Curious why you're looking for an alternative to Tropo if you've been happy with it.

Comment: because they dont have a service in the UK :(

Comment: cost is a reason; options to pay less are always nice to know.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit old, but for completeness sake, there is also Plivo that lets you run your own FreeSwitch servers and have an API on top of it that is similar to Twilio/Tropo: http://www.plivo.org/

However, noobs beware - this is not nearly as plug'n'play as Twilio or Tropo is, since you need a server to run FS and carriers to route the calls. Upside is that it's cheaper and you have much more control (at the cost of complexity).

Comment: great point on the noobs beware, but Plivo is definitely inexpensive.

Comment: Actually, this comment is now outdated. There is a difference between Plivo open source package and Plivo Cloud. The cloud offering found on Plivo.com is in the same realm as Twilio.